# Does calling IEnumerable.Cast<T>() changes the underlying type to something else, or the underlying type preserved?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Say I have `ISet<T> _set = new HashSet<T>();`

Now if I do: `_set.Cast<TInterface>().Contains(obj, comparer);` (where `T` implements `TInterface`), do I loose the `O(1)` benefit of the `HashSet<T>`?

In other words - does `.Cast<T>()`ing changes the underlying type (`HashSet<T>` in this case) to something else, or the underlying type preserved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, a `HashSet<T>` uses an internal hash-table based on the hashing logic of the comparer *that it was created with*, so of course it's not possible to do an element-containment test on it with a *different* comparer and expect O(1) performance.

---

That said, let's look at things in a  bit more detail for your specific scenario:

The `Cast<T>` method looks like this (from reference-source):

```
  public static IEnumerable<TResult> Cast<TResult>(this IEnumerable source) {
            IEnumerable<TResult> typedSource = source as IEnumerable<TResult>;
            if (typedSource != null) return typedSource;
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            return CastIterator<TResult>(source);
        }
```

As you can see, if the source implements `IEnumerable<TResult>` it just returns the source directly. Since `IEnumerable<>` is a covariant interface, this test will pass for your use case (assuming the concrete type implements the interface type) and the hash-set will be returned directly  - a good thing as there's still hope of its internal hash-table being used.

However, the overload of Contains you are using looks like this:

```
 public static bool Contains<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TSource value, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer)
        {
            if (comparer == null) comparer = EqualityComparer<TSource>.Default;
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            foreach (TSource element in source)
                if (comparer.Equals(element, value)) return true;
            return false;
        }
```

As you can see, it *always* loops through the collection to linear-search, which is O(n).

So the entire operation is going to be O(n) regardless.

Answer (score 1):

`_set.Cast<TInterface>()` will return an `IEnumerable<TInterface>` so `_set.Cast<TInterface>().Contains(obj, comparer);` doesn't invokes [HashSet.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), rather it invokes [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains%28v=vs.100%29.ASPX) extension method.

So obviously you don't get `O(1)` operation anymore.

If you need `O(1)` you again need to create a `HashSet` out of it.

```
   var newSet = new HashSet(_set.Cast<TInterface>(),comparer);
   newSet.Contains();
```

Comment: recreating new `HashSet` every time I want to test if some object is contained is high overhead

Comment: But if you want to test 1000's of items in a row recreating `HashSet` is a better option.

Comment: Don't think so: iterating until finding is only O(N) in the **worst** case (if you find it in the second index, that was O(2)..), while adding N items to whatever container is always O(N) - it's always the **worst** case

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I said if you want to check 1000's of items exist in a sequence which will be `O(N)` * 1000 but if you create only one `HashSet` and check for 1000 items it is just `O(1)` * 1000. Did you get me?

Answer (score 0):

The Cast method returns an IEnumerable so the Contains method will operate on the IEnumerable rather than the HashSet. So I think you'd loose the benefit of HashSet. Why don't you do the cast in the compared instead?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22934328/how-to-test-set-containsobj-when-set-is-hashsett1-obj-ist2-and-t1-t2-b