# How to test _set.Contains(obj), when _set is HashSet<T1>, obj isT2, and T1, T2 both implement same interface?

Tags: c#, polymorphism, c#-5.0

I must implement an `ObservableHashSet<T>` that can quickly (`O(1)`) test for object existence:

```
public class ObservableHashSet<T> : ObservableCollection<T>{
    readonly ISet<T> _set = new HashSet<T>();

    protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e){
        base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move) return;

        if (e.OldItems != null)
            foreach (var old in e.OldItems.Cast<T>())
                _set.Remove(old.GetHashable());

        if (e.NewItems == null) return;

        foreach (var nu in e.NewItems.Cast<T>()) _set.Add(nu.GetHashable());
    }

    public bool QuickContains(T obj){ return _set.Contains(obj); }
}
```

Now say we have two types, both implement same interface:

```
IDevice
  ├── ActualDevice
  └── DeviceClass
```

and the interface is:

```
public interface IDevice {
    string Vendor { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need a way to quickly (`O(1)`) test for certain `ActualDevice` existence in a list of `DeviceClass`s (`HashSet<DeviceClass>`). So how can I change the `ObservableHashSet<T>.QuickContains(T obj)` function above to allow it? so I'd be able to do something like this:

```
var classesList = new ObservableHashSet<DeviceClass>(someDataSource);
ActualDevice actualDevice = GetTheDevice();
MessageBox.Show(classesList.QuickContains(actualDevice) ? "Exists!" : "Missing...");
```

Comment: If an `ActualDevice` is equal to a `DeviceClass`, that sounds odd to start with...

Comment: `public class ObservableHashSet<T> : ObservableCollection<T>` is already wrong. A hash set is not an `IList`.

Comment: @Jon, of course it's not, but I need an observable collection that can be tested quickly (`O(1)`), which is a `HashSet`. How would you tackle it?

Comment: Why do you need the test to be `O(1)`? How many items are in your collection?

Comment: @Tal: Probably by aggregating a `HashSet` and directly implementing `ISet<T>` and `INotifyCollectionChanged` on top of it.

Comment: @Enigmativity - I have more than 300 items and I constantly test them

Comment: @Jon: First, it still leaves me with `HashSet<T>.Contains(T obj)` - it doesn't change the problem. Second, relying on `HashSet` for MVVM is somewhat problematic - you need index-based random access, to start with.

Comment: @JonSkeet - why is that odd? what I need to test is whether `ActualDevice` is one of certain list of `DeviceClass`es. It doesn't say that it's equal.

Comment: Why are you using an `ObservableCollection<T>` Are you binding to the UI or something? Something sounds really wrong with your code for performance on 300 items to be an issue.

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes, I'm binding to the UI, why else would I need `ObservableCollection<T>`?

Comment: @Tal: Not sure what you mean -- why is `HashSet.Contains` a problem? Regarding MVVM -- tough. If you want O(1) set operations *and* an ordered container at the same time you will have to implement it yourself (and perhaps adjust your expectations).

Comment: If you're binding to the UI then performance is probably one of your last concerns. Any performance benefit you get from a `HashSet` would be wiped out by any UI update. Just go with an iterative search and then profile your app to see if the performance issue is in searching for your devices.

Comment: @Jon, that's exactly what I'm doing - implementing it myself, and this question is about how to implement it...

Comment: You could also be using`ObservableCollection<T>` to enable updating of the `HashSet<T>`, not just for UI updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd make the item type of the `HashSet<T>` a class that only contains the data that you base the equality test on. At the moment you are trying to make a `DeviceClass` compare equal to an `ActualDevice` which seems odd.

My understanding is that you want to test whether an `ActualDevice` is associated with one of many `DeviceClass`'es. You could do it like this:

```
class DeviceClassKey : IEquatable<DeviceClassKey> {

 //Data members here
 int DeviceClassID; /* just an example */

 public static DeviceClassKey FromDeviceClass(DeviceClass dc) { return ...; }
 public static DeviceClassKey FromActualDevice(ActualDevice ad) { return ...; }

 //add equality members here
}
```

And now you add members to the set like this:

```
HashSet<DeviceClassKey> items = ...;
DeviceClass dc = ...;
items.Add(DeviceClassKey.FromDeviceClass(dc));
```

And you test membership like this:

```
HashSet<DeviceClassKey> items = ...;
ActualDevice ad = ...;
var isMember = items.Contains(DeviceClassKey.ActualDevice(ad));
```

I might have missed some requirement of yours but this technique can probably be extended to cover it.

Comment: If you need to retrieve the `ActualDevice`, you could use `Dictionary<DeviceClassKey, ActualDevice>`.